# How to join two elements together in scrapy?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to join all "The Text" parts into one string or one item in my scrapy output file. The source code below:

```
<div class="sth">
  <h3 class="sth">The Text</h3>
  <h4 class="sth2">
    <span class="sth11">The Text</span>
  </h4>
  <h4 class="sth3">
    <span class="sth11">The Text</span>
    <span>The Text</span>
  </h4>
</div>
```

Is there a good way to join all the "The Text" element all together into one item or one string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering you want any text that is children of the wrapping div, that you want to join them with a new line and you will run this inside a scrapy parsing method, you could:

```
"\n".join(response.xpath("//div[@class='sth']/descendant::*/text()").extract())
```

Comment: Thank for your help. If there are multiply same type class like  [class = "sth"] within the page source. How can I locate the specific one I want to scrape.

Comment: It is dependent on the real case, but for instance, if the div, with class sth you want scraped is the second of the page, you could do //div[@class='sth'][2]/...
Or use some other attribute(s) to better filter your xpath.

Comment: What if it is in the same page?

Comment: I meant in the same page, but the second div in that page with that class

Comment: The code join all the field, even though I use //div[@class='sth'][2]/